# Why importing cirq_ionq gives an unexpected argument error

Tags: cirq, ionq, programming

I'm trying to install cirq_ionq, a python library for running cirq circuits on IonQ's quantum hardware. However, when I try importing it I get an unexpected argument error:

```
!pip install cirq-ionq
import cirq_ionq
```

```
<ipython-input-8-d96952276b12> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install cirq-ionq')
----> 2 import cirq_ionq

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cirq_ionq/ionq_devices.py in <module>
     32     cirq.MeasurementGate,
     33     unroll_circuit_op=False,
---> 34     accept_global_phase_op=False,
     35 )
     36 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accept_global_phase_op'
```

I am confused why I am getting an unexpected argument error. I'm not calling a constructor, I am importing a library, right?

Could someone please explain this to me? I appreciate it.

Comment: You probably have a mismatch of `cirq-core` and `cirq-ionq` versions on your system. What do you get when you `pip show cirq-core` and `pip show cirq-ionq`?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Fu6mh6_RkblPFRAHA6yug_XdoDStkFo5I761dfvElM/edit?usp=sharing. The first image. I also have a code in google colab before code in SE question, which is in second image. That code returns a checkmark, likely because I already run it

Comment: Looks like your`cirq-core` and `cirq-ionq` versions match at `0.14.1` so that's not the problem. What happens if you `pip install --upgrade cirq-ionq` and try the `importing `cirq-ionq` again. This command should give you `cirq-ionq==1.0.0`.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks so much, I appreciate your time. But if I may ask, why wasn't it working before?

Comment: I can't know the cause without studying more than what you've posted, but my guess is that the install got messed up somewhere. We just installed the latest version of `cirq-ionq` just for testing to do a whole new install. Does the import still work if you do `!pip install cirq-ionq~=0.14.1`?